# Does this point to the class or a class instance? (6)

Tags: java

I realize this is a bit semantical but I'm trying to understand the best way to communicate an idea.

When using / describing `this` is it better to say it point to the class or the class instance?

Comment: this will always refer to "specific instance".

Comment: so it is wrong to say it points to the class - from my professors notes ( I think he is wrong ) - `The this keyword is a reference that always points to the
current class`

Comment: I would at-least bring up the point for discussion.

Comment: I'm officially done with this guys notes...he can't convey basic concepts accurately.  There is nothing to discuss really.

Comment: He seems to know what it does but he conveys it in a very confusing and ambiguous manner indeed...

Comment: Notes are in lecture 3 here - http://www.cs.nyu.edu/~cconway/teaching/cs1007/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [JLS §15.8.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.3):

> When used as a primary expression, the keyword `this` denotes a value that is a reference to the object for which the instance method was invoked ([§15.12](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12)), or to the object being constructed.

(Thanks to @assylias) The JLS *does* say that references point to objects so both "points to" and "references" are appropriate in this context.

Comment: @assylias Ok, fair enough. I wasn't aware that they used that terminology, I'll edit the answer.

Comment: FYI in 4.3.1 to be precise.

Comment: you are both smarter than a Columbia professor in this matter.  Thanks a bunch!

Comment: you should join the nativists.

Answer (score 3):

```
this
```

Always referes to the current `instance`, not the class.

[this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html)  docs

> Within an instance method or a constructor, this is a reference to the current object — the object whose method or constructor is being called. You can refer to any member of the current object from within an instance method or a constructor by using this.

Answer (score 2):

`this` always points `class instance`.It is the reference of `current class instance`.
According to [java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html)

> Within an instance method or a constructor, **this is a reference to the current object**

Answer (score 0):

**this refers to the Current Object of a Class.**

this can be used inside method or constructor of  class. It(this) works as a reference to current object whose method or constructor is being invoked. this keyword can be used to refer any member of current object from within an instance method or a constructor.